# Getting 403 error when trying to update profile description with Soundcloud PHP API

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

When I try to update the profile description of a soundcloud account via their php sdk, I get a 403 error every time. The app is authenticated and I am able to do things like place comments, but I'm not able to update anything on the profile (particularly the description field).

I'm using the standard code, found in their official documentation:

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with access token
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setAccessToken('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');

// get the current user
$user = json_decode($client->get('me'));

// update the user's profile description
$user = json_decode($client->post('me', array(
   'description' => 'I am using the SoundCloud API!'
)));
print $user->description;
```

Please help me find out where the error comes from, because I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Make sure you are having auth cookie during second request to Sound cloud

Comment: I'm using a session to store the auth in. I could definitely try using a cookie, but could that be it? I can post comments from the authenticated account already, for instance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our bad, the user documentation that you point to there had two problems:

- Updates to the user resource should use the PUT method, not POST.
- Arguments need to be namespaced properly.

I've modified the documentation to fix these two problems. New code sample:

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with access token
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setAccessToken('ACCESS_TOKEN');

// get the current user
$user = json_decode($client->get('me'));

// update the user's profile description
$user = json_decode($client->put('me', array(
   'user[description]' => 'I am using the SoundCloud API!'
)));
print $user->description;
```

Hope that helps and sorry again for the confusion. Let me know if you run into any more problems.

Comment: Great! That worked like a charm. We did think of using PUT instead of POST, but we didn't come up with the namespace change. Thank you for your help Paul!

Answer (score 0):

To update user related information you need to login to Sound Cloud as user and then authenticate your application to use your personal data, else you will get 403 for all user related information while updating / delete. For posting any comments you don't need this authentication

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication

Refer

**Getting Information about the Authenticated User**

Once the user has signed into SoundCloud and approved your app's authorization request, you will be able to access their profile and act on their behalf. We have provided a convenient endpoint for accessing information about the authenticated user.

Comment: Yes, but I have authenticated the user (my own account). I ran trough the authentication process and saved the auth token in a session. I'm able to retrieve all profile information (including the description) using the GET method. I just can't POST. I am able to use POST however, when posting a comment from the authenticated account, using the api. So this should mean the authentication is correct. But still when trying to update anything at the 'me' selector, it returns a 403. Everything else works perfect though..

Comment: Can you login to SoundCloud web site with your own account and make sure you approved your app's authorization request.

Comment: Yes, it has access. (I can see a button which says "Revoke Access")
But I don't think it's about the authorization, as I'm able to post comments using the API with that account.

Comment: I've looked into the authentication and have successfully made an authenticated call, using their example:

`code`
// make an authenticated call
$current_user = json_decode($client->get('me'));
print $current_user->username;
`code`

This works fine for me. Updating the description, still doesn't work however.